# Combine 2 dataframes and group by similar values next to each other

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

```
import pandas as pd 
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{'A':123456, 'B':'4/1/22'},{'A':234567, 'B':'4/1/22'},{'A':345678, 'B':'4/1/22'},{'A':567890, 'B':'4/1/22'},{'A':234567, 'B':'4/3/22'},{'A':456789,'B':'4/4/22'}])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{'C':159357,'D':'4/1/22'},{'C':234567,'D':'4/1/22'},{'C':234567,'D':'4/3/22'},{'C':234567,'D':'4/2/22'},{'C':234567,'D':'4/3/22'},{'C':456789,'D':'4/1/22'},{'C':654852,'D':'4/7/22'},{'C':753951,'D':'4/1/22'}])
```

I need df2 to join df1 by the same value (grouped). I have tried merging by using 'inner', but I don't want to lose any data from df1. So basically, if a number in df2 is seen in df1, align it with the first instance of the same value seen in df1.

My desired output:
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rx8RQ.png)

Thank you!

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, left_on=['A', 'B'], right_on=['C', 'D'], how = 'outer')`??

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need `how='outer'`

```
df1.merge(df2, how='outer', left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['C', 'D']).drop_duplicates()
```

---

```
           A       B         C       D
0   123456.0  4/1/22       NaN     NaN
1   234567.0  4/1/22  234567.0  4/1/22
2   345678.0  4/1/22       NaN     NaN
3   567890.0  4/1/22       NaN     NaN
4   234567.0  4/3/22  234567.0  4/3/22
6   456789.0  4/4/22       NaN     NaN
7        NaN     NaN  159357.0  4/1/22
8        NaN     NaN  234567.0  4/2/22
9        NaN     NaN  456789.0  4/1/22
10       NaN     NaN  654852.0  4/7/22
11       NaN     NaN  753951.0  4/1/22
```